# Getting Runtime Error, Uncaught(in promise): false, when passing an array value to navCtrl.push() in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to pass a value stored in an array to navCtrl.push() to navigate to another page, but it's not working.

The card below displays correctly in the HomePage

```
<div class="card-container ">
  <ion-card ion-button *ngFor="let card of cards"  (click)="cardSelected(card)">
    <img src="{{card.bg}}" />
    <div class="card-title">{{card.title}}</div>
    <div class="card-subtitle">{{card.subtitle}}</div>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

Now, when i click on the card i get the runtime error.

Here's the ts method

```
cardSelected(card){
 console.log(card.link); //output: AnotherPage
 this.navCtrl.push(card.link);  
}
```

Replacing card.link on the 3rd line with the page's name works.

```
cardSelected(card){
 console.log(card.link); //output: AnotherPage
 this.navCtrl.push(AnotherPage);  //this works
}
```

[here's the screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXEDN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `push` function looks like this:

```
push(page, params, opts)
```

The `page` needs to be of type `Page`, which is basically a component;

So make sure `card.link` is not a string, but an Angular 2 Component

**Ex:**

```
import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';


this.cards = [
  { title: 'Page One', link: Page1 },
  { title: 'Page Two', link: Page2 }
];
```

**Now your code will work:**

```
cardSelected(card){
 console.log(card.link); //good to go
}
```

**If you know the page your are going to but want to pass params:**

```
cardSelected(card){ 
  this.navCtrl.push(AnotherPage, {
     link: card.link
  });  
}
```

Then in the `AnotherPage`:

```
constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
     let link= navParams.get('link'); 
}
```